# Modal Pop up with Flex Column does not allow content to take its own height, but shrinks it?

Tags: html, css

I have modal pop up windows with the following structure:

The problem is when I open it on mobile device the text block is being cut off and is made to fit the popup no matter the height. How to make it to fit the content? The goal is to have the text element in its full height after that the image and if they are larger than the viewport to be scrolled within the pop up.

The problem appears when the viewport height is below 400px, the image takes almost half of the viewport and the text can't be seen.

```css
.modal-pop {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.modal-pop .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100vw - 40px);
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-pop .cover {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
}

.modal-pop .text {
  padding: 25px 15px 5px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-pop">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cover">
      <img src="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/320000/velka/background-image.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h2 class="title">Some test title</h2>
      <div class="pop-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Consequuntur dignissimos ducimus enim, error exercitationem facere facilis impedit, in ipsa, iste libero magni odio odit praesentium quaerat quo rerum sed voluptatum?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Consequuntur dignissimos ducimus enim, error exercitationem facere facilis impedit.</p>
        <p>In ipsa, iste libero magni odio odit praesentium quaerat quo rerum sed voluptatum?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please mmake a reproducible example that we can help you. Because just this code seems to work fine

Comment: @MaxiGui When you run the code snippet now here, and do not expand it to 100% you are not able to see the text, right? This is the problem, I want to be able to scroll trough the text first and see the image last. The situation appears when the height of the viewport is below 400px, for example on landscape mode on a phone

Comment: but then just move your img tag under you `p`. Why do you sset it into a cover ?

Comment: @MaxiGui Because this is the mobile layout, while in the desktop layout the image is on the left and the text on the right.

Comment: Ok what is the break point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the setting I made to make it work, I commented the following property that you have in your classes and Adjust img width to fit the container:

```
.modal-pop .wrapper {
  /*justify-content: flex-end;*/
}

.cover img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.modal-pop .text {
  /*overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;*/
}
```

The horizontal scroll you are having is due to:

```
.modal-pop .text {
  padding: 25px 15px 5px 15px;
}
```

So remove / adjust it and it should be gone.
You will need to adjust that with media query.

### DEMO

```css
.modal-pop {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.modal-pop .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100vw - 40px);
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  /*justify-content: flex-end;*/
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-pop .cover {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
}
.cover img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.modal-pop .text {
  padding: 25px 15px 5px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  /*overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-pop">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cover">
      <img src="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/320000/velka/background-image.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h2 class="title">Some test title</h2>
      <div class="pop-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Consequuntur dignissimos ducimus enim, error exercitationem facere facilis impedit, in ipsa, iste libero magni odio odit praesentium quaerat quo rerum sed voluptatum?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Consequuntur dignissimos ducimus enim, error exercitationem facere facilis impedit.</p>
        <p>In ipsa, iste libero magni odio odit praesentium quaerat quo rerum sed voluptatum?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### DEMO with order instead of column-reverse:

```css
.modal-pop {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.modal-pop .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100vw - 40px);
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  flex-direction: column;
  /*flex-direction: column-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;*/
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-pop .cover {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
}
.cover img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.modal-pop .text {
  padding: 25px 15px 5px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  /*overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;*/
}

.order-1{
  order: 1;
}
.order-2{
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-pop">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cover order-2">
      <img src="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/320000/velka/background-image.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text order-1">
      <h2 class="title">Some test title</h2>
      <div class="pop-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Consequuntur dignissimos ducimus enim, error exercitationem facere facilis impedit, in ipsa, iste libero magni odio odit praesentium quaerat quo rerum sed voluptatum?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Consequuntur dignissimos ducimus enim, error exercitationem facere facilis impedit.</p>
        <p>In ipsa, iste libero magni odio odit praesentium quaerat quo rerum sed voluptatum?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks awesome. Only 1 small detail left, do you think its possible when I run the snippet to make it start from the top and then to scroll it bottom? I think this is happening due to the column reverse?

Comment: Yes sure but to do so I would recommand you to use `order` from css instead of column-reverse it will be more effecient

Comment: I totally missed the change of ordering them with `order`. Thank you again with the all the help!

Comment: @Don40 you welcome. I still did a 2nd demo with order basic example. Of course, you need to adjust with media-queries after